# NodeJS - Upload to s3 without saving in local file system

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am receiving some text from a POST response in a REST API. I want to directly make a text file in s3 for that. All the examples I have stumble upon are using a local file and then uploading it. Is there any way to directly upload it without saving in the Local System?

Comment: I guess you can directly pipe it to s3.putobject

Comment: Or rather, `s3.upload`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly pipe the req to s3.upload function as below

```
import express from 'express';

import {S3} from 'aws-sdk';

const s3 = new S3();
const app = express();

app.post('/data', async (req, res) => {
    var params = {
        Body: req,
        Bucket: "yourbucketname here",
        Key: "exampleobject",
    };
    s3.upload(params, async (err, data) => {
        if(err)
            log.info(err);
        else
            log.info("success");
    });
});
const server = app.listen(8081,async () => log.info("App listening") )
```

The posted file will be directly uploaded to aws s3.

Comment: No, I'm not using a bodyparser anywhere

Comment: Interesting. The upload() method expects Body to be of type Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, or ReadableStream. How does the Express request object equate to one of those?

Comment: `req` is a stream

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the explanation. I read the Express routing API documentation, and it doesn't seem to explain anywhere what type 'req' is or indicate that it either is, or somehow implements, a readable stream.

Comment: Try this. Pipe your request to process.stdout in the route. `req.pipe(process.stdout)`

Comment: Doesn't this solution use local memory a bit. Because data stream should come to your server first and then go out to s3.